# vimrc,chinese word become messy code

Tags: vim

My operation system is ubuntu 14.04LTS
when I open a file in vim.The chinese words become messy code.
Then I search for resolution.The possible resolution is as below:
first,open `/etc/vim/vimrc`
secondly,added the three lines below:

```
set fileencodings=utf-8,gb2312,gbk,gb18030
set termencoding=utf-8
set encoding=prc
```

last,run `source /etc/vim/vimrc`

The error report tell me that it can't find command.

Comment: Which command cannot be found?

Comment: Did you run `source` in Vim or in the shell? It has to be in Vim (or just `:quit` and restart).

Comment: Don't modify the system file `/etc/vim/vimrc`; rather, create a user-specific `~/.vimrc` and put the customizations in there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the article [vim encoding-values](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/mbyte.html#encoding-values), it seems that you missed checking the first two steps:
1. Check whether you vim is compiled with `+multi_byte` supporting (`:version`);
2. Set shell's environment variable `$LANG` to appropriate value (for me, it's `en_US.UTF-8`).

Hope that helps.